# Unpacked gem in vendor/gems not in a versioned directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, unpack, vendor

I unpacked a gem into my `vendor/gems` directory and tried to run my Rails app.

I got this message:

```
Unpacked gem in vendor/gems not in a versioned directory
```

I don't understand this error and judging by the [Google search results](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&num=100&newwindow=1&q=%22Unpacked+gem%22+%22in+vendor%2Fgems+not+in+a+versioned+directory%22&aq=f&oq=&aqi=&fp=T9Jqn-g1Ucc) for this error there are not many people who have experienced this problem.

Could this mean I also need to vendor Rails to use `vendor/gems`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to vendor Rails to use vendor gems.

Normally gems unpack to a directory called something like `vendor/gems/some_gem-1.2.3`. Check that all your vendored gem directories follow this pattern (i.e. GEM_NAME-VERSION).

Answer (score 5):

The much easier and more robust way is to use [gem dependencies](http://railscasts.com/episodes/110-gem-dependencies).

Then if you want to unpack your gems into vendor/gems its as easy as typing:

```
rake gems:unpack
```

You do not need to vendor rails in order to vendor gems, the error appears to be a user error you are decompressing the gem into the wrong location and missing some version info.

Answer (score -1):

Did you do this manually or using rake? Since a gem in the `vendor/gems` directory has this format - `gem-name-VERSION`.

For example the `ruby-openid` gem will be unpacked to `vendor/plugins/ruby-openid-2.1.7/`.

Try using `rake gems:unpack` to unpack the gems.